# After installing Scala using MacPorts, scala command is not found

Tags: scala, macports

I am running Snow Leopard and installed MacPorts. I then installed the latest (as of this writing) Scala version as:

```
$ sudo port install scala29
```

What to do after this? When I try to execute the Scala interpreter, I get:

```
-bash: scala: command not found
```

Comment: I installed Scala on Mac OS X through the official IzPack installer (from http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads), and keep it up-to-date with sbaz. I recommend that, especially since even minor releases can have small incompatibilities (if e.g. they fix a bug you had a workaround for, and now you need to remove it).

Comment: I had a good experience with homebrew. "brew install scala" and "brew install sbt"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so I actually had to search this since the Scala install has changed since the last time I did it. The executables should have been linked from /opt/local/bin, to use them without prefixing the folders do this:

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo scala_select scala29
```

Now you should be able to run the scala command from any directory.

*As of January 2013 this answer is outdated, Arnost Valicek's answer is known to work.*

Comment: When I execute "port location scala", I get "Error: port location failed: Registry error: scala not registered as installed."

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. For us novices, there are so many ways to install Scala on a Mac that sometimes it's confusing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 52):

I'm using MacPorts 2.1.2 and things seems to changed a bit again.

```
$ sudo port select --list scala
```

Shows

```
Available versions for scala:
    none (active)
    scala2.9
```

Command suggested by nezda does not work properly:
    $ sudo port select --set scala2.9

gives error

```
Error: The 'set' command expects two arguments: <group>, <version>
```

But following helps

```
$ sudo port select --set scala scala2.9
```

Activates Scala 2.9

```
Selecting 'scala2.9' for 'scala' succeeded. 'scala2.9' is now active.
```

Checking scala again

```
$ sudo port select --list scala
Available versions for scala:
        none
    scala2.9 (active)
```

And I can run Scala now.

Comment: Worked for 2.10 as well, just increment the version.

Comment: Certified working with OS 10.10.5 Yosemite and scala2.11 on 12/25/2015.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to have changed.  On Lion + MacPorts 2.1.1, I had to do the following:

Verify this shows the version:

```
    sudo port select --list scala
```

Mine showed:

```
    Available versions for scala:
        none (active)
        scala29
```

If it is not selected, you can use this command to select it:

```
    sudo port select --set scala scala29
```

Open a new terminal (ensuring `$PATH` is up to date) and verify `scala` is now 2.9.x.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's:

```
sudo port select --set scala scala29
```

Comment: I modified my answer to add scala - I must not have copied the command I actually ran :)